# Cannot convert from System.Windows.Forms.Label to System.Windows.UIElements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a new label from the code behind (xaml.cs) in WPF at runtime. Because I want to create many objects, I can't create this objects in the beginning in the xaml-file.

What I tried in the xaml.cs-file:

```
Label newLabel = new Label();
newLabel.Text = "newLabelText";
myCanvas.Children.Add(newLabel);    // Error at newLabel
```

A part of my xaml-file:

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" ...
```

I get the following error.

```
Cannot convert fromt 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'
```

I couldn't find a solution on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two different namespaces. Your Label belongs to `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. You need to create System.Windows.Control Label.

Hopefully this code will work,

```
System.Windows.Controls.Label newLabel = new System.Windows.Controls.Label();
newLabel.Context = "newLabelText";
myCanvas.Children.Add(newLabel);
```

Comment: I changed the code, if it is okay for you. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Check the namespace. You're creating `Label` from `System.Windows.Forms` while you need `System.Windows.Controls`. Visual Studio sometimes adds a wrong namespace to using directive when automatically resolving namespaces on right click...